# Multiple condition within if statement within a function in PHP not giving desired result

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I am currently working on the title of a website where I have defined a function to give result from the database to show on the title section it works fine for condtion 1 & 2, however when I need it to display 'Home' i.e. when condition 1 or 2 are not set or empty it doesn't return 'Home'. I am hoping to have done something wrong with the 3rd condition but not sure where.

P.s: get_path() is a function that extracts url parameters to compare them with database values.

```
<?php
    function title($dbc){

            $path_info = get_path();
            $title_prod= $path_info['call_parts'][0];
            $title_cat = $path_info['call_parts'][1];

            if(isset($title_cat))
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE slugs = '$title_cat'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $titleslug = $row['subgroup'];

            } elseif(isset($title_prod))
            {           
                $query1  = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$title_prod'";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
                $titleslug = $row['product'];
             } elseif(!isset($title_prod) OR !isset($title_cat) OR isset($title_prod)==''  OR isset($title_cat)=='') 
             {
                $titleslug = 'Home';
             }
              return $titleslug;
              mysqli_close($dbc);
            }
        ?>
<title><?php echo title($dbc); ?></title>
```

Thanks in advance for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `isset($title_prod)==''` should be `$title_prod == ''` and 
`isset($title_cat)==''` should be `$title_cat` == ''.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my code. I fixed it however doesn't make any change :-(

Comment: Well, I don't know what get_path does, but if call_parts is empty, it works: https://eval.in/516506

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `isset` to a empty string as you did here:

```
 OR isset($title_prod)==''  OR isset($title_cat)==''
```

`isset` returns a boolean.

You should do this instead on that if:

```
elseif(!isset($title_prod) OR !isset($title_cat) OR $title_prod==''  OR $title_cat=='')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight mistake in your third condition:

```
elseif(!isset($title_prod) OR !isset($title_cat) OR isset($title_prod)==''  OR isset($title_cat)=='')
```

`isset()` returns a boolean value which means that one of these conditions will never be true `isset($title_prod)==''  OR isset($title_cat)==''`

I think you meant the following: `[...] OR $title_pord == "" OR $title_cat == ""`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with below change with title tag;

```
<title><?php if(title($dbc) != null){echo title($dbc)." | ".'Upperbit';}else echo "Home"  ." | ".'Upperbit'; ?></title>
```

Along with above changes as suggested. Perhaps I don't require a 3rd condition

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have changed the script according to correct `isset` syntax in this way:

```
elseif(!isset($title_prod) OR !isset($title_cat) OR $title_prod=='' OR $title_cat=='')
```

your script however has unexpected result because if, i.e., `$title_cat==''`, the first `if` statement is evaluated as `True`:

```
if( isset($title_cat) )
```

You have to change your code in this way:

```
if( $title_cat )
{
    (...)
}
elseif( $title_prod )
{
    (...)
}
else
{
    (...)
}
```